# EF Core global query filter caches the first filter value

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build multi-tenant application using .NET 5 & EF Core and I want to set global query filter to always include TenantId filter in any query

I tried many ways and followed the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#example) but the issue is that EF caches the first filter and doesn't get updated when TenantId is changed

I wrote the below code to simulate a changing TenantId per request:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.TenantId == TenantId);
        }

        public int TenantId => DateTime.Now.Second;
```

When I track the executed query, TenantId is always the same

Comment: It won't be cached if `TenantId` is a property of the context. Most likely your real code is different than what is shown here.

Comment: @IvanStoev you're right, it really works when I moved the property inside the context, thank you !
but Is there any way to depend on a property outside the context?

Comment: @Mahdy Did you find a way to depend on a property outside the context?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update **`tenantId`** comparision
from `x => x.TenantId == _tenantId` to `x => EF.Property<int>(x, "TenantId") == _tenantId`

```
 public class MyAppContext : DbContext
 {
        private readonly int _tenantId;
        public MyAppContext (int tenantId)
        {
            _tenantId = tenantId;
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //If your tenantId comparision is as following, then tenantId will not updated
            //modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.TenantId == _tenantId);

            //If your tenantId comparision is as following, 
            //then tenantId will updated every query excecution
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasQueryFilter(x => EF.Property<int>(x, "TenantId") == _tenantId);
        }
  }
```